# ProgressDialog no funciona en Listener Personalizado

Tags: java, android, activity, retrofit

Tengo un Listener personalizado

```
public interface CustomListener {
    void processDownload(boolean isSuccess,int process,int total);
}
```

Y la clase **ControllerRequest** que donde utilizo el *listener*, y tengo el metodo **onProcessDownload** que se utilizara para sobreescribir el los metodos del listener utilizados. Al igual en la clase activo el listener *customListener.processDownload(true,i,Total);*

```
public class ControllerRequest implements Callback<ResponseClass> {

    ActivityMain activity;
    Databasedb db;
    Context context;
    CustomListener customListener;

    public void start(Context context, String ps) {

        activity = (ActivityMain) context;
        db = new Databasedb(context);

        APInterfaces interfaces = ApiClient.getClient("").create(APInterfaces.class);
        Call<ResponseClass> call = interfaces.doRequest(ps);
        call.enqueue(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseClass> call, Response<ResponseClass> response) {
        int statusCode = response.code();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            if (response.body().getPermission().equals("danger")) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Error: " + response.body().getMessageWarning(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (response.body().getPermission().equals("isSuccesfull")) {
                int Total = response.body().getmyRequest().size();

                int i = 0;
                for (RequestClass myRequest : response.body().getmyRequest()) {
                    i++;
                    db.createTag(myRequest);
                    customListener.processDownload(true,i,Total);
                }
                db.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseClass> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    public void onProcessDownload(CustomListener listener){
        customListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Para finalizar y usar el listener en otra activity utilizo el metodo **onProcessDownload** de la siguiente manera.

```
private ProgressDialog progress;
......
......
progress = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
...................
progress.setMessage("Sincronizando...");
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.setProgress(0)
 progress.show();
................
    myinstance.onProcessDownload(new CustomListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void processDownload(boolean isSuccess, int process, int total) {
                        //progress.setProgress(total);
                        Log.e("processDownload: ", "Descargando: "+process);
                        progress.setMax(total);
                        progress.setProgress(process);
                    }
                });
```

Hasta aquí funciona correctamente todo excepto:

**progress.setProgress(process);**

**progress.setMax(total);**

Estas dos lineas son las que no funcionan, no me actualizan el dialogo.

En el logcat el listener es lo que me muestra, indicando que el listener esta escuchando los cambios que se generan desde la otra clase, el problema seria unicamente el dialogo.

```
*11-07 17:07:07.788 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 556
11-07 17:07:07.797 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 557
11-07 17:07:07.806 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 558
11-07 17:07:07.815 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 559
11-07 17:07:07.824 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 560
11-07 17:07:07.833 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 561
11-07 17:07:07.845 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 562
11-07 17:07:07.862 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 563
11-07 17:07:07.872 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 564
11-07 17:07:07.884 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 565
11-07 17:07:07.895 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 566
11-07 17:07:07.906 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 567
11-07 17:07:07.917 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 568
11-07 17:07:07.935 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 569
11-07 17:07:07.947 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 570
11-07 17:07:07.957 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 571
11-07 17:07:07.968 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 572
11-07 17:07:07.979 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 573
11-07 17:07:07.991 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 574
11-07 17:07:08.000 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 575
11-07 17:07:08.009 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 576
11-07 17:07:08.017 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 577
11-07 17:07:08.027 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 578
11-07 17:07:08.038 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 579
11-07 17:07:08.058 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 580
11-07 17:07:08.068 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 581
11-07 17:07:08.079 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 582
11-07 17:07:08.091 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 583
11-07 17:07:08.109 7348-7348/com.myapp.requestcomp E/processDownload:: Descargando: 584*
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al cerar el dialogo y ejecutarlo nuevamente muestra esto, pero durante el proceso no muestra nada, y claro al ejecutarlo nuevamente no cambia la información se queda con los mismos datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has imprimido la variable total?

Comment: Intenta especificandole al Dialog que no sea inderterminado asi: `dialog.setIndeterminate(false);` y dinos que pasa.

Comment: Cierto puede que el problema este en esa linea.

Comment: No funciona, al parecer tampoco es eso, lo que si no me había fijado esque cuando finaliza y esta a punto de cerrar el dialogo me muestra los datos, pero solo al final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo claro como explicarlo asi que hare el intento de hacerlo lo mas claro posible.

No estas haciendo una sincronizacion por porcentaje, sino que estas *imitando una sincronizacion* por porcentaje, lo que obviamente es diferente. Esto lo digo por esta parte del codigo:

```
if (statusCode == 200) {
{
 //...
```

El estatus 200 indica que el servidor envio la respuesta. Una peticion puede durar un momento indefinido de tiempo segun la velocidad de internet del usuario y tu dialogo de carga va estar como si no estuvieria sincronizando en cero, por estar esperado una respuesta del servidor. Una vez el servidor te responde con la data es cuando intentas emular que esta cargando cuando en realidad ya cargo la data con la respuesta del servidor.

Dicho esto, aqui es donde puede estar el problema:

```
 int Total = response.body().getmyRequest().size();
    int Total = response.body().getmyRequest().size();

    int i = 0;
    for (RequestClass myRequest : response.body().getmyRequest()) {
        i++;
        db.createTag(myRequest);
        customListener.processDownload(true,i,Total);
    }
    db.close();
```

Aqui es donde guardas la data y actualizas el `ProgressDialog` segun el numero de la iteracion. El problema esta en que como la data ya esta en memoria, esto puede ocurrir rapido, muy rapido y eso puede explicar el porque solo se ve al final que completo porque no le da el chance al sistema de actualizar el porcentaje.

Lo mejor que puedes hacer cambiar un dialog de progreso de porcentaje por uno indefinido y que al momento de terminar de guardar la data en la base de datos, lo cierres y asi te evitas confundir a nosotros, a los usuario y a ti mismo.

Comment: Si seria la menera más sencilla de solucionar, quizas termine cambiandolo por un progressbar o con noficicaciones este ultimo ya lo eh implementado y me ha funcionado. Y tienes razon de alguna forma en el hilo se realiza el proceso correctamente pero en la UI es como si se quedara congelado el proceso y hasta que finaliza el hilo vuelve a reaccionar el dialogo (UI).